# Return date based on a condition in Power BI using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

hope you can help me.
I need to calculate in Power BI a date difference between today() and a certain date based on a condition.

I have a calendar table with the date (calendario[fecha]) related to a fact table ASID to predict column ASID[amount] and a measeure [Estimado] that gives me the linear regression

```
    Estimado = 
VAR Known =
    FILTER (
        SELECTCOLUMNS (
            ALLSELECTED ( 'calendario'[fecha] ),
            "Known[X]", calendario[fecha],
            "Known[Y]", [ASID]
        ),
        AND (
            NOT ( ISBLANK ( Known[X] ) ),
            NOT ( ISBLANK ( Known[Y] ) )
        )
    )
VAR Count_Items =
    COUNTROWS ( Known )
VAR Sum_X =
    SUMX ( Known, Known[X] )
VAR Sum_X2 =
    SUMX ( Known, Known[X] ^ 2 )
VAR Sum_Y =
    SUMX ( Known, Known[Y] )
VAR Sum_XY =
    SUMX ( Known, Known[X] * Known[Y] )
VAR Average_X =
    AVERAGEX ( Known, Known[X] )
VAR Average_Y =
    AVERAGEX ( Known, Known[Y] )
VAR Slope =
    DIVIDE (
        Count_Items * Sum_XY - Sum_X * Sum_Y,
        Count_Items * Sum_X2 - Sum_X ^ 2
    )
VAR Intercept =
    Average_Y - Slope * Average_X
RETURN
    ROUND(
        SUMX (
            DISTINCT ( calendario[fecha] ),
            Intercept + Slope * calendario[fecha]
    ),0)
```

My visualization matrix has 3 columns: calendario[fecha], it's real value [ASID] and the estimated measure [Estimado].
I have a limit of 1105 for that ASID.
I can see that at a future day, let's say a month from now 03/12/2020, the estimated reaches a value of 1105 (after scrolling all the matrix), so I need a way to capture that day and be able to calculate 03/12/2020 - today() and display somewhere: "30 days left"

Raihan: I could use the datediff as you suggested
[matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lg3NS.png)
Is there a way to capture just the 231 value?

DAX is now: if([Estimado]>1105, DATEDIFF(TODAY(),LASTDATE(calendario[fecha]),DAY),0)

Comment: to answer your updated question to capture the single value of the date differences please refer to my edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't provide the sample dataset and you didn't tell about your measure formula I just consider a sample dataset on my own to simulate your problem.

Consider following screenshot with data and calculated columns.

[image]

Here the DaysFromToday calculate the Day difference from Today to for every column if the corresponding value in 'SomeValue' field reached a certain number. SomeValue is also calculated field that you can replace with your own calculation.

To get the single value from DaysFromToday you can have a measure which will give you MAX or MIN (of course some others functions if you need) of the column values like following screenshot -
[image]

Yellow highlighted is the DAX way of mentioning a field name with the table name that you are missing in your formula.

Lastly the MAX or MIN measure can be displayed in the report like following -

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Raihan, seems like it goes that way. With that example, I just need the difference with September 20, 2021. When I try to use your formula with my fields, I don't get to pick my calendar table in the DATEDIFF. I'm trying IF[Estimado]>100, DATEDIFF(TODAY(), <I would use the Calendario[fecha] field right?>, DAY),0).

Comment: I could attach a screenshot of the matrix with your suggestions! I just need to retrieve the first difference value

Comment: @gusch I've updated the answer replying your issues mentioned in your comment.

Comment: You are a genius Raihan... it worked perfectly. I struggled with the 0 in the IF, cause using the MINX would return the first date with 0. But I changed that to 9999 and it worked!!!! thank you very very much

Answer (score 0):

it will be better if you can provide sample dataset and sample answer that you want.

Comment: Thanx Su25, seems like I can't upload an image, it would be way easier to show. I tried to describe the problem all over again with more details